# RabbitMQ on Windows seems to limit connection creation per process

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, messaging

I want to understand the behavior I'm seeing with the following code. Using the RabbitMQ.Client library version 6.2.2.

**Expected behavior:** Connections are created quickly and the process does not slow down.

**Actual behavior:** First 6 connections are created quickly, after that there is a significant slowdown and connections are created one by done (1s apart).

Note; starting the program multiple times shows similar behavior. That leads me to believe that the bottleneck is per-process rather than RabbitMQ or system resources.

Note 2; system resources are not the bottleneck (AFAIK).

Does anybody know what is causing the observed behavior? RabbitMQ installed on Windows 10 with default settings.

```cs
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
                var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

                var channel1 = connection.CreateModel();
                var channel2 = connection.CreateModel();

                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I know this violates every best practice regarding "Single connection per process". I'm just curious what is limiting the connection creation and if there is any setting that can control this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET client uses the `ThreadPool` which probably doesn't have enough threads out of the box. You need to increase the amount available:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/main/projects/TestApplications/MassPublish/Program.cs#L21

See issues and discussion here:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/search?q=threadpool